# How do I have to configure a dataprovider for Sitecore 8.2.5 so its constructor is called by the Sitecore Kernel?

Tags: c#, xml, sitecore, dataprovider, sitecore8.2

We upgraded from Sitecore 8.1 to 8.2.5 and one of the dataproviders we use, but did not code ourselves is not working anymore.

So far we could trace the problem to the constructor never being called by the Sitecore Kernel on the intial loading of the page, which prevents the dataprovider from working properly.

We have not changed anything in our config files, but as far as we know 8.2 has changed how dependency injections work.

Config file entries:

```
<sitecore database="SqlServer">

<events timingLevel="none">
    <!-- Dataprovider Events -->
    <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.Dynamic.DynamicDataProviderNotification, Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common" method="OnItemSaved"/>
    </event>
    <event name="item:saved:remote">
        <handler type="Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.Dynamic.DynamicDataProviderNotification, Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common" method="OnItemSavedRemote"/>
    </event>
    <event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.Dynamic.DynamicDataProviderNotification, Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common" method="OnPublishComplete"/>
    </event>
    <event name="publish:end:remote">
        <handler type="Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.Dynamic.DynamicDataProviderNotification, Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common" method="OnPublishComplete"/>
    </event>
    <!-- /Dataprovider Events -->
</events>

<pipelines>

    <publishItem>
    <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.DetermineAction, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.PublishPreventer, Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common" />
    </publishItem>

</pipelines>

<!-- DataProvider -->
<dataProviders>
    <DynamicDataProvider type="Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.Dynamic.DynamicDataProvider, Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common" patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)DataProvider, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
</dataProviders>
<!-- /DataProvider -->

<!-- DATABASES -->
<databases>
    <database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <icon>Images/database_master.png</icon>
        <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
        <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
            <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
            <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
            <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Master.config" />
            </prefetch>
        </dataProvider>

            <!-- Custom Changes Start -->
        <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/DynamicDataProvider"  patch:after="*[@ref='dataProviders/main']"/>
            <!-- Custom Changes End -->

        </dataProviders>
    </database>
    ...
<databases>
```

Beginning and constructor of our dataprovider:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;

namespace Company.WCMS.PROJECT.Common.DataProvider.Dynamic
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using Sitecore.Caching;
using Sitecore.Collections;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.DataProviders;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

using System.Collections.Concurrent;

using Name.Framework.ClassGenerator;

using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Events;
using Sitecore.Publishing;

public class DynamicDataProvider : DataProvider
{
    public static readonly ID OrginalFieldId = new ID("{f8ea7f10-f7f6-4c5a-a409-097728cc3f55}");

    private static readonly MD5CryptoServiceProvider Md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    private static readonly List<Action<IBaseSitecoreItem>> RefreshHandler = new List<Action<IBaseSitecoreItem>>();
    private static readonly List<Action<Database, bool>> ClearIdsHandler = new List<Action<Database, bool>>();

    private readonly HashSet<ID> rootItems = new HashSet<ID>();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ID, HashSet<ID>> realToFakeId = new ConcurrentDictionary<ID, HashSet<ID>>();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ID, FakeIdBucket> fakeCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<ID, FakeIdBucket>();
    private readonly List<IDynamicDataProvider> providers = new List<IDynamicDataProvider>();
    private readonly Dictionary<ID, List<IDynamicDataProvider>> tempalteToProviders = new Dictionary<ID, List<IDynamicDataProvider>>();

    private static string ItemIcon = Settings.GetSetting("Leister.Internet.DataProvider.ItemIcon", string.Empty);

    public static event Func<IBaseSitecoreItem, bool> RefreshItem;

    public DynamicDataProvider()
    {

        this.LoadProviders();

        RefreshHandler.Add(this.RefreshLocal);
        ClearIdsHandler.Add(this.ClearIds);
    }
```

RefreshHandler is always empty as the constructor is never called which prevents other functions from working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is an order issue.   Before you add any providers in your code you must add to RefreshHandler.  Nothing in the code posted does either.  I suspect the configuration is being returned in ItemIcon and the nothing is done with ItemIcon.

Comment: I don't think this matters too much since the constructor is never even called and this code is never run.

Comment: There is a deserialize method that is being called from DataProvider class.  the standard Net Library Serialize Class does work with Dictionaries.  So I suspect it has something to do with the dictionaries.  You can search the web for Net Library Dictionary Serialize to see solutions.

Comment: I see, but as we suspected it was a problem in the config files. Sitecore changed the Database type name from Database to DefaultDatabase and we did not notice that and so our patch referred to the wrong type. We adjusted that and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we suspected it was a problem in the config files. Sitecore changed the Database type name from Database to DefaultDatabase and we did not notice that and so our patch referred to the wrong type. We adjusted that and now it works.